# Puppet - moving from manifest to ENC script & Dashboard

Tags: puppet, dashboard

I install open source puppet on the servers. 
Puppet server have Puppet 3.3.1 and on agent puppet 2.7.25.

Until now I work with manifest file. Now I would like to create a perl/php script 
that will create the YAML script and should overwrite the manifest files.

I edit the file puppet.conf and put:

```
mode_terminus = exec
external_nodes = /usr/bin/env PUPPET_DASHBOARD_URL=http://localhost:3000 /path/to/bin/external_node
```

In the file /path/to/bin/external_node I put my code for the perl script.
when I run Puppet on the agent, it's look like it still take the manifest instead of the script I put.

Also, 
How can I send parameters to the script? 
How to access to fact variables from the script, like $hostname etc?

After this part will work I would like to make it visual from the Dashboard too.
Thanks.

Comment: I have been able to accomplish this sort of thing with https://github.com/crayfishx/hiera-http

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

The problem was spelling mistake!

It change it to 'node_terminus = exec'.

node with 'n' and not with 'm'.

Thanks.